# Arduino - Qt C++ Serial Interface

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, arduino-uno

I recently started to learn Arduino and Qt programming . I have a question , recently i made a small project , where if a particular digital port is high , then the counter in the arduino will count -1 , and then it will keep increasing . Then i send this data through the serial port to the Qt app, where i used a LCD display to display the data . So far i was successful. My question now is , lets say i am having a second LCD display in the Qt C++, and want to send a different serial data to the second LCD display , how can it be done . Based on my understanding , on LCD one i am using readAll(); which reads all the serial data . How can i differentiate data that is coming from the Arduino and display accordingly in the LCD display . Thank you for your help and response . I am using Arduino Uno board .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this seems to be by laying out a packet scheme to encode data. For instance, you can send 2 consecutive bytes with the first being for LCD 1 and the second for LCD 2. Read the string in, parse out the 2 bytes and assign them to the appropriate display.